# Método delete da numpy fazendo coisa estranha

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

eu tava testando o método delete da classe array da biblioteca numpy e aconteceu uma coisa estranha: Eu mando excluir o elemento de indice 0 do array, porém é excluido o elemento de indice 1. Não tô entendendo o que esse delete tá fazendo

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> lista = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
>>> lista
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
>>> lista[0]
1
>>> lista = np.delete(lista,lista[0])
>>> lista
array([1, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `delete` da biblioteca numpy remove um sub-array com base no índice e não no valor do elemento a remover.

No seu exemplo o que pretende fazer é:

```
lista = np.delete(lista,0) #indice 0 a ser removido
print(lista) #[2 3 4 5 6]
```

Pode até passar uma lista de indices a serem removidos, fazendo:

```
lista = np.delete(lista,[0,1,3]) #indice 0, 1 e 3 a serem removidos
print(lista) #[3 5 6]
```

[Veja ambos os exemplos no Ideone](https://ideone.com/ringvz)

[Documentação para o np.delete](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html)